# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=10.0.0.0' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, sql-server

Recently I have started using SSMS 2017 (v17.5). In my MVC application, I am getting the following error.

`Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies.`

Only thing changed in my application is `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types` version which is `14.0.0.0` now. Previously, it was `12.0.0.0`.

Following are different options I have tried so far based on my research (this includes another `stackoverflow` articles + google) but I am getting same error.

1. Add `<dependentAssembly>` in `app.config`

```
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0-11.0.0.0" newVersion="14.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

2. Adding following line in `Global.asax.cs` in `Application_Start` method.

```
SqlProviderServices.SqlServerTypesAssemblyName = "Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91";
```

3. Installing `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types` using `NuGet`.

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.SqlServer.Types
```

4. Searched for `10.0.0.0` referance in entire project but didn't find any referance.
5. I do have `Microsoft System CLR Types for SQL Server` installed for `2012, 2014, 2016` and `2017`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I assume your query is running against SQL Server 2017? Does your table have a `hierarchyid` column?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yes it is running against 2017. No, that table does not have `hierarchyid`.

Comment: Any other eccentric data types? Could you show the `CREATE TABLE` along with indexes?

Comment: @CSharper Is the build failing locally or on a remote server? Also, when you mentioned searching for that assembly, did you search via the solution explorer? In the "Search Solution Explorer" text field above the solution, put in `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types` then you'll see all projects that have references to it. Check the properties of each reference to `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types` and see which one is targeting 10.0.0.0

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I just found the solution and added my answer below. Hope that make sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After spending almost a day, I was able to fix this issue. From my question above, option-1 worked for me. Only tweak was to add that in `web.config` instead of `app.config`. Hope this help someone else.

Code: web.config

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-14.0.0.0" newVersion="14.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Comment: Thanks, that tip lead me to a fix. Not quite the same though. Through VS I added (re?) added a reference to Microsoft.SqlServer.Types for the project (right click project, add reference, under extensions). It added version 13. In my web.config, I simply changed Version=10.0.0.0 to Version=13.0.0.0 . Managed to hack my way around this old app I had not touched in maybe 2 years...

Answer (score 2):

For a net library project that have the same error, I go to NuGet packages and install this library:

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.Types
```

and its works.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft.SqlServer.Types -Version 14.0.314.76 is the current version. try changing your version number. Second, check your .csproj file, Application also maintains its dependencies in .csproj file

Comment: My `.csproj` file has the same version.

Comment: then try cleaning your project, delete all bin/lib and then rebuilding your project (If you hav'nt tried it already).

Comment: That didn't help either.