# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types,Version=15.0.0.0,Culture Neutral,PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'

Tags: c#

I'm a C# Developer, and i encounter a problem when i create the `DataSet` type (especially `TableAdapter`).

[image: Creation of Table Adapter In DataSet Problem]

I installed the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types` package from Nuget Packages Solution
but still the same thing.

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types,Version=15.0.0.0,Culture
>   Neutral,PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies.
>   the specific file is not found.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=10.0.0.0' or one of its dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49739137/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-sqlserver-types-version-10-0-0-0-or)

Comment: You have to update the .proj file for the project.  You change the version of SQL Server.  I normally create a new project and add just the changed library.  Then compare my non working .proj file with new .proj file.  Then edit non working .proj file to look like new file.  It is easier to edit the proj file then to crate a new project and add all the module to the new project.  The VS update process is not very robust and often gives errors like this after libraries have been changed.

Comment: I Solved the Problem by : Repair the Microsoft Visual Studio using "Visual Studio Installer"

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you can install the SQL CLR tyes from here:

x86: https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/c26a74d5-dea2-4470-8710-f55d9fc6b1cf/f00a12b4f626a834e6ad7cc5fabe9d4c/sqlsysclrtypes.msi

x64: https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/dc6a8061-56b7-4c39-950c-c0b6d938bc4c/c390e88ef49173e8c7b1b00174da2a25/sqlsysclrtypes.msi

Answer (score 0):

I'm on visual studio 2019 community edition and use data source i will try update to 2022 next

1. Select Tools > Import and Export Settings from the menu bar to open
   the Import and Export Settings Wizard.
2. In the Import and Export Settings Wizard, select Reset all settings,choose no to
   save current
3. restart visual studio and data source worked